# My potion is unreliable!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a custom potion, and while testing it, I found that at random times it would simply not give me the potion effect. The potion is not at fault; I have even tried some from the creative menu. It only happens in a certain area. My first guess was lag, but none of the normal lag-fixing measures, for example, restarting minecraft,are effective.

The potion's command is:

```
/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:25,Amplifier:14,Duration:20}]}
```

EDIT: I have noticed that in a minority of cases, the potion effect is given some 5 seconds after drinking the potion

Answer (score 1):

The `/give` command works differently with potions than with normal items. Try This:

```
/give @p potion 1 8193 {CustomPotionEffects: [{Id:10,Amplifier: 127,Duration: 200000}],display: {Name: "Potion"}}
```

with your duration, amplifier, and ID. If you're still having trouble, try [using a Potion Generator](https://minecraftcommand.science/potion-generator) which will create the command for you. If you're still having problems, reinstall Minecraft with your saves saved, and re-start your device.

Comment: `Amplifier` is saved as a byte, with a minimum of -128 and maximum over 127. Exceeding that value will cause it to overflow and not work as you desire.

Comment: @skylinerw Thanks... I was thinking of `/effect` where you can go to 255 with the multiplier!

Comment: @Skylinerw I'd call that a 8 bit signed integer though.

Comment: @Dodekeract Why? That's much more of a mouthful. See also, ["byte" in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).